# Why do we need to check whether .play() returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code have the `promise !== undefined` condition?

```
var promise = myPlayer.play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(function() {
      // Autoplay started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Autoplay was prevented.
    });
```

I understand that `myPlayer.play()` returns a Promise.
But when I `console.log` that promise:

```
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

So I don't understand why we need this condition: `promise !== undefined`...?

Comment: whaaat.. the test to see if promise is undefined makes sense because if it is, `promise.then` would return an error.. the promise's RESULT may be undefined but that's different from the variable promise beginning as undefined ;-;

Comment: Presumably because there are conditions where `myPlayer.play()` will return `undefined` … but since we don't knoww hat `myPlayer` is we can't tell what those are. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a browser that is up-to-date, it will always return a Promise and the if-statement will be unnecessary. But when writing code for websites, we usually need to consider different browsers and versions. Browser versions released before 2019 [may not return a value after invoking `.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play#return_value).

When a function in JavaScript doesn't return a value, it implicitly returns `undefined`, so that is what is being checked here. If you call `.then()` on a variable that is `undefined`, it will throw an error.

```js
const promise = undefined;

promise.then(function() {
  // Autoplay started!
});
```

Comment: Excellent, clear, spot-on answer.